# service entry keeps disappearing from manifest

Tags: java, android, git, maven, android-studio

I recently implemented an intent service in my app and wondered why i wasnt able to start it.

```
Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.myapp/.service.DownloadSerive } U=0: not found
```

After checking git status i found that the previously added service  entry in manifest was removed.

```
- <service android:name=".service.DownloadSerive"/>
```

After readding and building it surpise, surprise: 
**It was gone again!**

I`m not sure what to do now and also kind off blocked on finishing my service.

***How can manifest changes just vanish? Does AndroidStudio do stuff in it?***

Comment: Which manifest file are you modifying? If by chance you're modifying the merged manifest in the build folder then yes, Android Studio outputs a new version as part of the build process

Comment: Thanks for your question Scott, it was something similar. Looking deeper into the project i found some weird maven configuration replacing the main Manifest which goes into apk with one from a subfolder. thats more than odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Scott Bartas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2985303/scott-barta) comment i found that some weird maven execution overrode the main manifest with one from some subfolder anytime at build.

```
<execution>
                        <id>copy-android-manifest</id>
                        <!-- here the phase you need -->
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <useDefaultDelimiters>false</useDefaultDelimiters>
                            <delimiters>
                                <delimiter>${*}</delimiter>
                            </delimiters>
                            <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>AndroidManifest.xml</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}/config/</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
```

**Conclusion:**

***I dont think that any Android Studio or the build process itself might ever be changing the manifests contents.***

***When facing the problem it can be suspected that somebody implemented it, intended or not.***